# Cuando hacer dispose() en mi conexión y como mejorar mi conexión al SQL C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buen día,

Actualmente estoy reformando un proyecto de otro programador donde no hacia buenas practicas en el uso del SQL (concatenaba cadenas, etc). Mi duda ahora, es saber como poder optimizar la conexión a mi base de datos cumpliendo con las normas.

Ejemplo, al hacer un INSERT.

```
myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");
            mysqlcommand_insert.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

            mysqlcommand_insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contactos ([IdContacto],[TipoContacto],[CUITCUIL],[CUITFiscal],[RazonSocial],[DNI]" +
           ",[Nombre],[Apellido],[Nacionalidad],[FechaDeNacimiento],[ClaveFiscalAFIP],[CUITAGIP],[ClaveAGIP],[ClaveARBA],[Descripcion],[Condicion])" +
           " VALUES (@contacto_id,@tipo_contacto,@cuit,@cuit_fiscal,@razon_social,@dni,@nombre,@apellido,@nacionalidad,@fecha_nacimiento,@clave_fiscal" +
           ",@cuit_agip,@clave_agip,@clave_arba,@observaciones,@condicion)";

            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contacto_id", txt_cod_contacto.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_contacto", cbo_tipo_contacto.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit", txt_cuit_cuil.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit_fiscal", txt_cuit_fiscal.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@razon_social", txt_razon_social.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", txt_cod_dni.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txt_nombre.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", txt_apellido.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nacionalidad", cbo_list_paises.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nacimiento", dtp_fecha_nacimi.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_fiscal", txt_clave_fiscal_afip.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit_agip", txt_cuit_clave_agip.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_agip", txt_clave_agip.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_arba", txt_clave_arba.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@observaciones", txt_observaciones.Text);
            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condicion", cbo_condicion.Text);

            mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

            mysqlcommand_insert.Parameters.Clear();
            mysqlcommand_insert.Dispose();
            myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Como regla general toda clase que implemente la interface [IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netcore-3.1) contiene un método `Dispose()` que debe ser invocado de manera implícita dentro de un bloque [`using(...){ }`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) o explicita dentro del `finally` en un bloque [`try-finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) o [`try-catch-finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally)

En el código que publicaste, no veo invocación del método `Dispose()` en ninguna parte y eso va a causar fugas de memoria, una la puedo apreciar a simple vista, pero hay otras que no son tan fáciles de identificar porque el código es confuso.

En  la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks) de la clase `SqlConnection`, se puede leer que los métodos `Close` y `Dispose` son funcionalmente equivalentes, pero esto es para `SqlConnection` y no debe asumirse que sea igual para otras clases.

Aunque tienes un método `cerrar_conexion();` que hace un `Close()` a la conexión creada,  la forma como lo utilizas no garantiza su ejecución en todos los casos.

Por ejemplo, en el código INSERT:

```
myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");   
mysqlcommand_insert.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

// código omitido   
// ... 

// Aquí tienes una fuga de memoria
// y si se produce una exception, cerrar_conexion no se ejecuta
mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteReader();

myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

En el código anterior, la fuga de memoria se produce porque el método `ExecuteReader()` devuelve un objeto `SqlDataReader` que no se está descartando. Para este caso deberías utilizar el método [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks)

Si todo sale bien al enviar el insert a la base de datos, `cerrar_conexion()` se ejecuta sin problemas, pero si se produce una exception no.

Una forma de resolver lo antes mencionado sería la siguiente:

```
myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");   
mysqlcommand_insert.Connection = myCls_general.myConnection;

// código omitido   
// ... 

try
{
    mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    //Aquí se recomienda hacer log de la exception 
    throw;
}
finally
{
    //el bloque finally siempre se ejecuta sin importar
    //si el try falla o no
    myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
}
```

Un ejemplo más, con un método tomado de la clase Conexión

```
public DataSet sqlcommand_select(string strSQL)
{
    //Retorna un dataset
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    //Declara el Adaptador fuera del try para poder referenciarlo en el finally
    SqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myConnection);
    try
    {
        Adaptador.Fill(dataSet);
        return dataSet;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
         Adaptador.Dispose();
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

La intención de esta respuesta es proporcionar una guía que sirva como punto de partida.

El código sugerido representa una opción sin hacer grandes modificaciones al código existente, pero no es la única.

Tampoco mencioné todas las mejoras que se me ocurrieron porque la respuesta se extendería mucho.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Pablo, me podrias indicar si como lo estoy manejando ahora, está mejor?

Está corregida la pregunta.

Comment: Mejoró solo un poco, sin embargo ten presente que si la instrucción `mysqlcommand_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();` falla, el resto de las instrucciones no serán ejecutadas, y eso puede causar fugas de memoria. Por eso en mi respuesta incluí un ejemplo con `try-catch-finally`

Comment: Vale! Lo voy a hacer. Te consulto, como puedo mejorar todo este tema de conexión a la base de datos? El proyecto está hecho en una sola capa.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que con mi respuesta lo que intento es darte una guía de algunos aspectos fundamentales. Hablar de cómo mejorar el código es un tema muy extenso  para tratarlo en el formato de StackOverflow, además está basado en opiniones y puntos de vista. Lo mas recomendable al momento de refactorizar código es ir introduciendo cambios progresivamente para no perder el control ni romper la aplicación. Por eso mis recomendaciones sugieren cambios basados en el código existente y no algo más radical.

Comment: Gracias pablo! Es grato aprender de gente como ustedes que están más avanzados. Progresivamente he ido cambiando todas las consulta, insert, update a la forma que te fui mostrando. Estaban sin parametrizar y poco a poco he ido avanzando.

Answer (score 0):

Para las conexiones a base de datos lo mejor es utilizar un scope seguro. Microsoft proporciona el using statement para estos escenarios. Normalmente esto se hace con una clase que implementa la interfaz IDisposable pero si esta utilizando el namespace System.Data.SqlClient no es necesario ya que esas clases ya implementan esa interfaz https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement.
Entonces por ejemplo usted podría hacer algo como esto:

```
  var consulta = "INSERT INTO Contactos ([IdContacto],[TipoContacto],[CUITCUIL],[CUITFiscal],[RazonSocial],[DNI]" +
           ",[Nombre],[Apellido],[Nacionalidad],[FechaDeNacimiento],[ClaveFiscalAFIP],[CUITAGIP],[ClaveAGIP],[ClaveARBA],[Descripcion],[Condicion])" +
           " VALUES (@contacto_id,@tipo_contacto,@cuit,@cuit_fiscal,@razon_social,@dni,@nombre,@apellido,@nacionalidad,@fecha_nacimiento,@clave_fiscal" +
           ",@cuit_agip,@clave_agip,@clave_arba,@observaciones,@condicion)";

            using (var conexion = new SqlConnection("Aquí va la cadena de conexión"))
            {

                await conexion.OpenAsync();

                using (var comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion))
                {
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contacto_id", txt_cod_contacto.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_contacto", cbo_tipo_contacto.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit", txt_cuit_cuil.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit_fiscal", txt_cuit_fiscal.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@razon_social", txt_razon_social.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", txt_cod_dni.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txt_nombre.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", txt_apellido.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nacionalidad", cbo_list_paises.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_nacimiento", dtp_fecha_nacimi.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_fiscal", txt_clave_fiscal_afip.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuit_agip", txt_cuit_clave_agip.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_agip", txt_clave_agip.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clave_arba", txt_clave_arba.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@observaciones", txt_observaciones.Text);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condicion", cbo_condicion.Text);

                    
                    var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    //otras instrucciones


                }

            }
```

Como puede observar no se esta cerrando la conexión a la base de datos en ningún lado porque esto lo administra .NET si se hace de esta forma.

Recomiendo también este ORM :https://github.com/arsoftcr/noef con el que se podría ahorrar bastante tiempo. Es de licencia abierta y lo puede instalar como paquete nuget en visual studio entonces  podría guardar la cadena de conexión en un ConnectionString y enviar los parámetros como un diccionario de datos y de el resto se encarga el ORM.

Comment: Vale. Perfecto! Haciendo esto y con la consulta como la tengo parametrizada, estaría todo "dentro de las buenas practicas"? Soy nuevo en esto, trato de leer y leer, pero a veces no es suficiente, por eso recurro acá.

Comment: Te podría robar el tiempo de con el ejemplo del INSERT que tengo en el cuerpo del mensaje, hacer algo como lo que me mostraste.

Comment: Consulta parametizada, asyn/await y using statement. Me parece que estaría más que bien. Le dejo el ejemplo. Recuerde que el método debe tener las palabras clave async y Task<bool>  o Task<Type> el objeto que se quiera retornar para poder hacer uso de await